# Replace values in XML file with values of a vector

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have an XML file and I need to replace the value that comes right after "type" with a value from a vector `v=[7,8,9]` using a Python code. I need the code to recognize the word "type" and then change the value of the parameter in the following line. The value 2 should be replaced by `v[0]`, 3 by `v[1]` and so on. Is there a way to do this with ElementTree or with readlines?

```xml
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>2</param>
      <param>5</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>y</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>3</param>
      <param>2</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>z</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>7</param>
      <param>9</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
```

Comment: Follow this approach [processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390556)

Comment: There's a simple way to do it with lxml. Hopefully the question will be reopened (I'm not sure why it was closed in the first place), at which point I would be able to post it.

Answer (score 3):

we can change values using the module `xml.etree.ElementTree`.
In code child represents `Function` tag and child[x] represents `x`<sup>th</sup> element in the `Function` tag.By using `text` attribute we can access values of elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
v = [7, 8, 9]
for child in root:
  child[2].text = str(v.pop(0))

tree.write('output.xml')
```

**Another Approach:**

we can also solve by comparing the elements, if element text is equal to `type` then we update the value next to it.

```
elements = root.findall('Function/param')

for i in range(len(elements)):
  if elements[i].text == 'type':
    elements[i + 1].text = str(v.pop(0))

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: Nice use of `v.pop(0)`; very elegant!

Comment: I need the code to recognize the word "type" and then change the value of the parameter in the following line

Comment: @ElenaPopa Than you should edit the question and state that explicitly.