# Replace values in XML file with values of a vector using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have an XML file and I need to replace the value that comes right after "type" with a value from a vector `v=[7,8,9]` using a Python code. I need the code to recognize the word "type" and then change the value of the parameter in the following line. The value 2 should be replaced by `v[0]`, 3 by `v[1]` and so on. Is there a way to do this with ElementTree or with readlines?

```xml
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>2</param>
      <param>5</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>y</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>3</param>
      <param>2</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>z</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>7</param>
      <param>9</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
```

Comment: Don't you have the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60430194/407651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(model)
v = [7, 8, 9]
targets = doc.xpath('//Model/Function/param[.="type"]')
for target in targets:
    chn = target.xpath('following-sibling::*[1]')[0]
    chn.text = str(v.pop(0))
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>7</param>
      <param>5</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>y</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>8</param>
      <param>2</param>
    </Function>
    <Function>
      <param>z</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>9</param>
      <param>9</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
```