# AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am attempting to iterate over an XML file using Python. Here is a code snippet:

```
for fields in root.iter('context'):
        for ID in fields.iter('ID'):
            try:
                name = ID.attrib['name']
                if name in fields_to_remove:
                    removed.append({'name': name, 'tag': ID})
            except KeyError:
                pass
        if removed:
            comment = ','.join([ ID['name'] for ID in removed])
            for ID in removed:
                fields.remove(ID['tag'])
            fields.append(ET.Comment('Removed ' + comment))
            removed = []
```

XML example:

```
<context name="Subscription" category="subscription" type="generic" optimizeSize="1">
                <field name="DELTA_MID_RT" type="bool" id="-1" defaultValue="false"/>
                <field name="API::TZO" type="int32" id="-1" defaultValue="0"/>
                <field name="API::DIVIDENTADJUST" type="bool" id="-1"/>

        </context>
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 20, in <module>
    for fields in root.iter('context'):
AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'
```

Comment: Which parser did you use? Please update the code so we can see where `root` comes from!

Comment: Same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616800/elementtrees-iter-equivalent-in-python2-6

Comment: Indeed same problem. Same answer. Also creates new problem :)